# Get whole url without preset parameters

Tags: regex

So I have this regex for getting a YouTube link

```
/(http|https):\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(\w+)/i
```

But the problem is that it won't pick up the end of the link of something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID&sdfgsdfgsdfg;jsfdg;lkjsdf;gkj

It picks up `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID` and leaves `&sdfgsdfgsdfg;jsfdg;lkjsdf;gkj` alone. I want it to pick up the whole string while still extracting the video ID.

Comment: What do you mean "pick up the whole string"?  `v=(\w+).*` ?

Comment: It probably stops at `&` because that is not matched by `\w`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thanks but I'm looking for something where it will stop  looking for a match after it finds a space. Using that, I can have the URL + a full paragraph after it and it will match the whole thing into the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?.*?&?v=(\w+)(?:&[^\s]+)?/i
```

- `https?` is the same as `(?:http|https)`, you didn't say you needed to capture the protocol
- `/watch\?`...

  - `.*?` - Consume any additional query parameters
  - `&?` - If there are other query paramters, then there will be an `&`
  - `v=(\w+)(?:&[^\s]+)?` - Capture the VideoID and, optionally, the rest of the URL up to whitespace

Comment: Unfortunately that captures more than the rest of the URL. I want to be able to have readable text after the URL and the match is picking up everything, even if there's a space there (probably because of the usage of the period)